# Information about hazarat khizar

Tags: sunni

As salam o 3laikum dear my muslim brother,

May Allah give you success in the mission you are onto and in the life hereafter.

My question to you is that I have been going through many scholars telling about Hazrat Khizar, but I did not come across with any specific and authentic reference from The Holy Quran or Sa7i7 Hadeeth regarding Hazrat Khizar specifically by his name. I have only come to know about him by the assumptions of the scholars.

Can you provide me the information about Hazrat Khizar that when was he born and was he a prophet upon any nation or wali of his times or having any other designation? is he still alive or no? is there mentioned any where in the Holy Quran or Sa7i7 Hadeeth about him?

It will be very kind of you if you enlighten us upon this.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE, the Q&A site about Islam. We strongly recommend you to take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarise with what Islam SE is about and visit the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to     learn about the stack exchange model. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need help on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

First his name is/was al-Khidr (or al-Khizr which IMO is a wrong transliteration of the Arabic word الخضر).

Secondly his name was indeed not mentioned in the Quran, but he was attributed as man that has been given knowledge from or by Allah in the story of Moses/Musa in surat al-Kahf.

Thirdly i don't know what you call sahih hadith, in the answers of the relevant posts on this site we have posted links to ahadith from sahih al-Bukhari and Muslim where his name is clearly mentioned. So your claim is simply wrong.

Your questions on the whole are not new.

See for example:
[Why does Moses seem to take Khizr slaying a boy lightly?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33209/13438)

[Is Al Khidr alive?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35208/13438)

[Why did Al-Khidr kill a boy who had not committed any sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2464/13438)